# Problem binding Sub-Objects to a ListView in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, binding

I have an ObservableCollection of Measurement-Objects

```
Dim measurement As New Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection(Of Measurement)
```

Where Measurement is

```
Public Class Measurement
  Public Property Value As Single
  Public Property Unit As String
  Public Property Enviroment As Enviroment
End Class
```

and Enviroment is (simplified)

```
Public Class Enviroment
  Public Equipment As String
End Class
```

now I bind this Collection to a ListView

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <ListView.Resources>
        <my:SingleToStringConverter x:Key="singleToString"></my:SingleToStringConverter>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="ValueTemplate">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value, Converter={StaticResource singleToString}}"></TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.Resources>
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Value" CellTemplate="{StaticResource ValueTemplate}"></GridViewColumn>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Unit" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Unit}"></GridViewColumn>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Enviroment" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Enviroment.Equipment}"></GridViewColumn>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

To be complete; the Converter is:

```
Public Class SingleToStringConverter
  Implements IValueConverter

  Public Function Convert(ByVal value As Object, ByVal targetType As System.Type, ByVal parameter As Object, ByVal culture As System.Globalization.CultureInfo) As Object Implements System.Windows.Data.IValueConverter.Convert
    Return CSng(value).ToString(Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
  End Function

  Public Function ConvertBack(ByVal value As Object, ByVal targetType As System.Type, ByVal parameter As Object, ByVal culture As System.Globalization.CultureInfo) As Object Implements System.Windows.Data.IValueConverter.ConvertBack
    Return CSng(value.ToString)
  End Function
End Class
```

but the ListView does not show any property of the SubObject Eviroment. It does not support INotifyPropertyChanged, but I'm sure that it exists before it is added to the collection. But there is now values displayed.
Can anyone please help?

Comment: I'm trying to do something similar. Can you tell me: where you put this xml?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You try to bind to a field instead of a property. I think your Enviroment-Object should look like this:

```
Public Class Enviroment
    Public **Property** Equipment As String
End Class
```

You can't bind to public fields.